# Logarithmic differentiation. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out if there's a general rule to applying logarithmic
differentiation. Do the times usually involve exponents?

Here's an example that I think I got wrong. Where did I go wrong?

$$y = x^{\sin{x}}$$
$$\ln{y} = \sin{x}\ln{x}$$
$$\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{\sin{x}}{x} + \ln{x}\cos{x}$$
$$ y' = x^{\sin{x}}(\frac{\sin{x}}{x} + \ln{x}\cos{x})$$

But wolfram alpha has:

$$x^{\sin(x) - 1} \cdot (\sin(x) + x \log(x) \cos(x))$$

Comment: Those are the same answer...

Comment: Maybe you can show me how?

Comment: $x^k\cdot (\frac Ax +B)=x^{k-1}(A+Bx)$

Comment: Oh I guess if you multiply part of a side by x you have to divide the other side by x too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the same answers. Most notably$$\begin{align*}x^{\sin x}\left(\frac {\sin x}x+\cos x\log x\right) & =x^{\sin x}\left\{\frac 1x\left(\sin x+x\cos x\log x\right)\right\}\\ & =x^{\sin x-1}(\sin x+x\cos x\log x)\end{align*}$$